# constrain predictions within outer knots in mgcv::gam using R

Tags: r, spline, gam, mgcv

I would like to fit a cubic spline using the `gam` function in `mgcv` package in R. Furthermore, I would like to constrain values outside of the training set (beyond the outer knots) to be equal to the nearest knot value. That is, no model prediction should be done outside the range of the training data. I know I can do this simply by eliminating those points in the `predict` call and then setting them to the min and max of the training data. However, is there a built in method in `gam` to do this (just so it's a bit cleaner?)

Example code:

```
require(mgcv)
x = 10:90
y = x^2
mdl = gam(y ~ s(x, bs="cr"))

needed_x = 1:100
p = predict(mdl, newdata = list(x = needed_x)) #this returns model values form 1:9 and 91:100
```

Comment: Do you want it to be the nearest _knot_ value, or the nearest _fitted value_ within the range of the data?

Comment: Look at the `perimeter` function in pkg:rms. Does not do exactly what you want but does create a boundary for any two dimensions that strives to limit predictions outside of plausibility for 2 way interactions.

Comment: @HongOoi: nearest knot value